# Alexa calendar: Amazon Lambda local vs UTC timezone mismatch

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I went through the exercise of building an [Alexa Skill to read local events](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-calendar-reader)from an ics calendar. It all works fine, except that whenever there's an event starting at 7 pm EDT or later, the skill reads it out as the next day.

This seems to be a time zone issue. I'm hosting the logic on Amazon Lambda, which I believe is set to UTC. Setting my Google calendar to UTC doesn't help. Adding `process.env.TZ = 'America/New_York'` to my JavaScript node.js code doesn't help either.

I'm told that for privacy reasons, I can't discover the time zones of Alexa users. But I don't need to discover the time zone of the skill users, since it's a safe assumption that they're all in the same time zone as my local events calendar, Eastern Daylight. All I need to do is have lambda know that events between 7 pm and midnight local time don't happen on the next day. Any ideas what I can do? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UTC is the only unambiguous and deterministic time zone  for times in the past and in the future, as well as now.

It is the only time zone where, for example, regardless of the actions of local or national government actions the time one second after 01:59:59 will *never on any date* be 03:00:00.  US/Eastern, on the other hand, experiences this once a year in the spring. Conversely, there are two times on one day in fall where the wall clock time 02:59:59 occurs twice in one day, one hour apart.  But in UTC, these two times are correctly represented by two distinct values that are 3600 seconds apart, with one occurring an hour after the other.

When designing an application to handle datetimes, there's little room for debate that the correct solution is to store datetimes as UTC and then use a time zone library to convert them.  Converting to UTC is the only way to assure a lossless conversion.

[Google calendar follows this best practice](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37064?hl=en&visit_id=1-636353344329244384-1334977078&rd=1)  and does not store your events in your local time zone, instead converting and storing all events as UTC and then converting again and displaying them according to your calendar's time zone preferences.

If (?) it's a safe assumption that the user wants to hear the events based on America/New_York, then use a time zone library to convert both the system's date/time (any server should always have its "local" time zone set to UTC, and this is the case for Lambda) and the event date/times from UTC to the target time zone before doing your comparison.

Presumably, the Google Calendar API can also be queried for your time zone preference, and you can use that value for the conversions. Or you can ask the user.

Comment: There's plenty of discussion about time handling here: https://zachholman.com/talk/utc-is-enough-for-everyone-right